# How to create a snapshot volume to a remote server using kvm?

Tags: centos, backup, virtual-machines, remote, snapshot

I want to backup a few virtual machines to a backup server. Here're the backup steps.

```
suspend a virtual machine
create a snapshot of the virtual machine using lvcreate -s
resume a virtual machine
dd if=/virtual_machine_path | lzop > /temp/backup.lzo
rsync /temp/backup.lzo -e "ssh " 1.2.3.4:/backup_path/
```

However, the hypervisor server doesn't have enough hard disk space to create a snapshot in step 2. Is there a way to create a logical volume snapshot to a remote server?

Comment: Which Hypervisor are you using?

Comment: I'm using KVM and libvirt.

Comment: I don't suppose adding more storage to your VG is an option?

Comment: Each virtual machine has a different size. If a newly created virtual machine has a very large disk space, then a lvm snapshot would cause a disk space shortage, no matter the storage I add.

Comment: LVM snapshots only use space for any changes, taking a snapshot of a 500GB volume does not require 500GB for the snapshot unless 500GB of writes happen before you're done with the snapshot.

Comment: That's right. I couldn't predict how many changes would happen after a snapshot is created. If making a snapshot volume too small, it would be filled quick and become invalid. If making a snapshot volume auto extends, it would take more disk space.

Comment: Are you not using thin provisioning in your LVM volumes?

Comment: No, I'm not using thin provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with netcat.

```
dd if=/virtual_machine_path | gzip -o - | nc 1.2.3.4 1234
```

Then on 1.2.34, do

```
nc -l 1234 > backup.gz
```

Comment: I can only backup a virtual machine from its snapshot. Is there a way to combine netcat and lvcreate -s ?

Comment: You have to create the snapshot regardless, but the snapshot is just another LVM logical volume so you can use the path to it directly.

Comment: How to create the snapshot logical volume to a remote server?